# Setup kerberos on windows 7

Tags: kerberos

I am developping a java web application application for a client which use kerberos spnego to authenticate its user. Kerberos itself is "plugged" to a LDAP

They send me a documentation with what to put in my web.xml to get the authenticated user in my web apps.

But I would like to be able to test my configuration before sending my war in production.
I know nothing in kerberos.

Do you know if it is possible and how to install on my local host (windows 7 x64) a kerberos that allow me to test my application.

Something with fake user, fake group, fake permission.

Do you know some software or tutorial, something to start with ?

thanks !

Comment: What is the production web server and environment? Windows? Linux? What is being used for Kerberos? Your dev environment should match production as closely as possible.

Comment: it is a windows + ldap, yes I would like to match as close as possible but if I can setup any kerberos it will be a good start

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Active Directory, of course. Which is probably what's in your production environment.

Set up a VM with a domain controller running Windows Server and a second VM with your web server, joined to the domain you just set up in the first VM. Get your license keys from your MSDN account.

Comment: Looks not easy to set up. In particular login a user from a VM to a domain from another VM. But now it gives me a clear idea how to do it thanks!